# Unable to create abstract - child classes with json schema

Tags: jsonschema, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

I am trying to create a parent - child relationship using json schemas. I have tried different approaches but all are failing. I have the abstract definition of AbstractRequest:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/abstractReply",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "transactionType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["PORTFOLIO_REQUEST", "ADD_STOCK_REQUEST", "GET_STOCK_REQUEST"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["transactionType"]
}
```

and I want a child request that is linked to this one. This is what I have currently:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/portfolioRequest",
  "description": "Portfolio Request",
  "unevaluatedProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "https://example.com/schemas/abstractReply"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "portfolioId": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Id of the portfolio"
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "User Id of the request"
        }
      },
      "required": ["portfolioId"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also tried referencing the abstractRequest directly within the child but nothing happens.

Right know if I use this set up 2 things will happen:

1. AbstractRequest is generated but is not abstract (is a normal
   class)
2. PortfolioRequest is not generated at all

I am using jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin to autogenerate.

I appreciate the help :)